# Group output in JSON file according to job title (role name)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

The code below works as far as outputting data from my JSON file. However, I want to be able to output according to the "Role Name". So if it is an Associate editor, that persons information should be placed in that section. If they are Editor and Chief, they are placed in that section. If they are Editorial Advisory Board, they are placed in that section  Below is my html, followed by my JS. First, I copied some of my json.

Json Data:

```
[
  {
    "Journal: Journal Name": "Accounts of Chemical Research",
    "Role Name": "Editorial Advisory Board",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Full Name": "Joanna Aizenberg",
    "Last Name": "Aizenberg",
    "Institution": "Harvard University",
    "Address1": "School of Engineering Applied Sciences",
    "Address2": "29 Oxford Street",
    "City": "Cambridge",
    "State/Province": "MA",
    "Country: Country Name": "United States",
    "Postal Code": "02138",
    "Country Region": "Western Hemisphere",
    "Journal Email": "jaiz@seas.harvard.edu",
    "Office Email": "jaiz@seas.harvard.edu",
    "Initial Appointment Date": "1/1/19",
    "Active Role Tenure Start Date": "1/1/19",
    "Active Role Tenure End Date": "12/31/20"
  },
  {
    "Journal: Journal Name": "Accounts of Chemical Research",
    "Role Name": "Editorial Advisory Board",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Full Name": "Ayyappanpillai Ajayaghosh",
    "Last Name": "Ajayaghosh",
    "Department": "Chemical Sciences and Technology Division",
    "Institution": "CSIR-National Institute for Interdisciplinary Science and Technology",
    "Address1": "Industrial Estate PO, Pappanamcode",
    "City": "Thiruvananthapuram",
    "Country: Country Name": "India",
    "Postal Code": "695 019",
    "Country Region": "South Asia",
    "Office Email": "ajayaghosh62@gmail.com",
    "Other Email": "ajayaghosh62@gmail.com",
    "Initial Appointment Date": "1/1/17",
    "Active Role Tenure Start Date": "1/1/20",
    "Active Role Tenure End Date": "12/31/22"
  },
  {
    "Journal: Journal Name": "Accounts of Chemical Research",
    "Role Name": "Editorial Advisory Board",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Full Name": "Scott L. Anderson",
    "Last Name": "Anderson",
    "Department": "Department of Chemistry",
    "Institution": "University of Utah",
    "Address1": "1224 Henry Eyring Building",
    "Address2": "315 S. 1400 E., Rm 2020",
    "City": "Salt Lake City",
    "State/Province": "UT",
    "Country: Country Name": "United States",
    "Postal Code": "84112",
    "Country Region": "Western Hemisphere",
    "Office Email": "anderson@chem.utah.edu",
    "Initial Appointment Date": "1/1/15",
    "Active Role Tenure Start Date": "1/1/18",
    "Active Role Tenure End Date": "12/31/20"
  }
]


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/masthead-old.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="masthead.css">
</head>
```

Html code:

```
<body>
 <main>
  <!--<div id="editorList"></div>-->
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <h1>Journal of the American Chemical Society</h1>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h2>Editor-in-Chief</h2>
      <div id="editorChief"></div>
      
     </div>
    </div> 
      
    <!--Associate Editors-->
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
       <h2>Associate Editors</h2>
       <div id="associateEditor"></div>
      
     </div>
    </div> 
      
   <!--Editorial Advisory Board-->  
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h2>Editorial Advisory Board</h2>
       <div id="eab"></div>
     </div>
   </div> 
         
 </div>
  
</main>    
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
        
    
    
    $.getJSON("jci-test-file.json", function(dataJCI){
        console.log("hell0");
        //var journalName =dataJCI[i]["Journal: Journal Name"];
            //var fullName= dataJCI[i]["Full Name"];
            //var int=dataJCI[i]["Institution"];
              //$("#editorList").append("<h2>" + journalName + "</h2>").append("<h3>" + fullName + "</h3>").append ("<h4>" + int + "</h4>");
      

  
        
        editorList(dataJCI);
        
    });
    
    
  });




function editorList(dataArray){
    console.log("hello");
    var journalList=[];
    for(i in dataArray){
         if (dataArray[i]["Journal: Journal Name"]==="Journal of the American Chemical Society"){
             journalList.push(dataArray[i]);
        //Content of the current postion in dataArray has been placed inside my new array, which is journalList
     
         }
    
    }
    console.log(journalList);
    displayContent(journalList);
}


//group them by role name first before displaying content









//create a function to display the content
//Create proper HTML structure to properly format page. 

function displayContent(journalList){
    for(i in journalList){
       //var journalName =journalList[i]["Journal: Journal Name"];
       var fullName= journalList[i]["Full Name"];
       var int=journalList[i]["Institution"];  
        $("#editorList").append("<h3>" + fullName + "</h3>").append ("<h4>" + int + "</h4>"); 
     
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you take your problem and reduce it to a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

This works with your data, I've tested.

```js
data.reduce((a,c) => {
  let role
  if(role = a.find(_a => _a["Role Name"] === c["Role Name"]))
    role.persons.push(c)
  else
    a = [
      ...a,
      { "Role Name": c["Role Name"], persons: [c] }
    ]
  return a 
},[])
```

```
[{…}]
  0:
    Role Name: "Editorial Advisory Board"
    persons: Array(3)
      0: {Journal: Journal Name: "Accounts of Chemical Research", Role Name: "Editorial Advisory Board", Gender: "Female", Full Name: "Joanna Aizenberg", Last Name: "Aizenberg", …}
      1: {Journal: Journal Name: "Accounts of Chemical Research", Role Name: "Editorial Advisory Board", Gender: "Male", Full Name: "Ayyappanpillai Ajayaghosh", Last Name: "Ajayaghosh", …}
      2: {Journal: Journal Name: "Accounts of Chemical Research", Role Name: "Editorial Advisory Board", Gender: "Male", Full Name: "Scott L. Anderson", Last Name: "Anderson", …}
      length: 3
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I appreciate you taking the time to look at this. Can I ask, where exactly did you add that?

Comment: I am glad to help. I think I really don't understand what you are asking hehe, but if you ask where did I ran the tests, just copy/pasted your json data in Chrome Devtools and started to try a solution in there.

Comment: If an answer solves your question don't forget to flag it as "Correct answer", so the community knows this topic is done and the solution remains visible for anyone that has a similar issue.